# I want to update the todo list but when I try to update it add new todo task

Tags: django, django-views, backend

I want to update the todo list but when I try to update it add new todo task

[The screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuRRc.jpg)

```
def updateTask(request, pk):
    task = Task.objects.get(id=pk)

    form = TaskForm(instance=task)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TaskForm(request.POST, instsnce=task)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')

    context = {
        'form': form
    }

    return render(request, 'update_task.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `instsnce` to `instance` in this line of code

```
form = TaskForm(request.POST, instsnce=task)
```

Because your instance parameter name is incorrect, TaskForm could not get the updated object and understand that it needs to create a new one.